# Programmatically detect the best fit in the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm drawing and saving plots to my disk and look each of them to find the correct plot. Is there a way to find out the best fit? I have tried to use standard deviation of the list. But as numbers go high, std goes higher.

Below you can see two different plots. First one, visually matches my criteria. However, the second plot doesn't seem good.

[image]

1. Best fit:
2. Bad fit:
   [image: Plots]

Comment: Do you need to deduce this from the plot? Why not fit a model to the data

Comment: if you're trying to match to a straight line with gradient of say (130,000-95,000)/300, then you can create that straight line and calculate the least squares error ie (x1-x2)^2. The plots that have less deviation from your desired line (e.g. a straight line) will have lower least squared errors

Comment: all i am trying to do is simply loop and change variables to find the best linear line

Comment: @JimmyOnThePage what exactly do you mean by fitting a model?

Comment: Sounds to me like you are trying to perform linear regression on your data set. During simple linear regression, your data is used to fit the parameters for a straight line equation. There's tons of literature available of this online